# Select option using jade returned Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

```
select
  option(value='1', ((#{obj.active} == 1) ? 'selected' : '')) Candy
```

What's wrong with my jade above? I'm trying to to selected a option (dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use selected={condition} to make the option as selected. So the below code should work

```
select
  option(value="1", selected=(obj.active == 1)) Candy
```